# Finding a block of HTML appearing before header.phtml on Magento Site

Tags: html, magento

I have been asked to update a Magento site, however, I have not had much experience with Magento in the past. So far, I have been able to apply the changes required, but I have just hit a road block, and cannot find where a certain bit of code is stored.

The code in question is right at the beginning of the `body` section, but it is located before the beginning of the `header.phtml` file. I have also looked in the `head.phtml` file, but it is after that. There appears to be a block of about 15 elements (including a google analytics script) that appears after the opening `body` tag, and before the `header.phtml` content. I have checked the static blocks, but cannot find anything in there. Does anyone know where else to look?

**EDIT**

I have been checking the included files, but so far, I cannot identify which file the code is located in. I had done a test to see what files where being included and when, and I have determined that the `/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Helper/Data.php` file is being included, then the `notices.php` file, and when inspecting the code, I can see that the code is being included right after `<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->`, and right before the `notices.php` file is included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last, found it. It was within a file called `1columns.phtml` which I had assumed contained only layout information for a part within the page, but it contained the functions that called the header, notices, and the other code. I found it with a php script written to do a recursive search through all the files within the director `/app` searching for the unique identifier

Answer (score 2):

- Use Firebug. Inspect that HTML element and find to see if you can identify the class or some other naming thing to know which block is rendered
- Turn on template path hints, you will come to know which template is used to display that HTML. You can then easily find the Block attached to it.

To turn template path hints: `System >> Configuration >> Developer, change Current Configuration Scope to website >> Debug Template Path Hints, set it to Yes.`

Comment: I have tried that, but it didn't really reveal any more information sadly. The code snippet starts if with some <!--[if statements to determine the browser, within each one (and an else) there are opening div tags with the a common class of `class="wrapper"`, and for the other if statements, inclusions of classes such as `ie ie6 lte9` depending on what browser it is. It then contains some span elements that have unique names, but are just used for applying some funky objects to the site

Comment: Get some text you seem different in that block HTML, and search it in your template's directory to know where it comes from. Or can you show the URL or part of that text here?

Comment: I would love to, but I have no ability to access the server other than FTP, and I am running Windows 8, so no search through files unfortunately :(

Comment: No problem. If you can use Firebug for firefox and inspect element on that block HTML, it will atleast give you hint where to look for.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the HTML you need to edit could be anywhere.  It might have been added via a `phtml` block in the layout (`app/design/`), or it could be be coming from PHP module code in an observer (`app/code/community`, `app/code/local`, or even `app/code/core` if someone's dropped a core hack in place).

There's a few ways to approach solving this.  First, turn on Template Path Hints for your store view (it won't show up for the default configuration scope)

```
System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Debug
```

This will make your frontend render with outlines around most of the block on the page.

It that doesn't help, use `grep`, [`ack`](http://beyondgrep.com/), or your favorite text-searching program to search the entire source tree for a unique bit of HTML from the part you're trying to edit.

Finally, there's more powerful, Magento specific debugging tools available.  I sell one called Commerce Bug ([demo](http://commercebugdemo.pulsestorm.net/)), [this article](http://alanstorm.com/find_magento_block_name) includes a description of it's block diagramming features, which would be applicable to the problem you're currently facing.  If you're going to be doing a lot of Magento work, it's worth investigating a tool like this.